# @main Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

im getting the error

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

I know what it means but I have absolutely no clue what my code is doing that triggers this error, because I don't get it in a line like this:

```
array.remove(at: 5)
```

but there:

```
@main
```

(In my Main File)

Is there a way to figure out what triggers that error?

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: The crash occurs if `array` contains 5 or less items.

Comment: The code line was only an example, this crash occurs because of a line in my real code, and the problem is that I don't know which line because the error shows on `@main`

Comment: It's not necessarly a remove. It can be `array[5]` that triggers the issue... You should have stacktrace in console, which might tell you from where your issue is coming...

Comment: Do you have a `UITableView`? one of the common reasons for this error is if your app is trying to dequeue the row in table view that doesn't exist

Comment: @KirilS. no im only working with SwiftUI

Comment: Why would the error even show up at the `@main` part instead of where it gets triggered?

Comment: Because the debugger is not perfect. I have the same issue with a runtime error right now. I know where the error is coming from, but it shows on the `@main`. If you want help, you need to most a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb But there wasn't a stackstrace in console output to help find out the issue?

Comment: I have the same situation. I am going to be using one of my technical assists to get my problem figure out as it isn't be solved here. It happens, and unless you post an MRE, no one can help.